# Bigquery Standard SQL Date to First Day of Month

Tags: google-bigquery

How do you convert a date in YYYY-MM-DD format to the first day of the month in BigQuery Standard SQL?

Answer (score 13):

Use `DATE_TRUNC`:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('2017-02-17', MONTH);
```

Or, for a more interesting example where the input is strings in the format of `YYYY-MM-DD`:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(CAST(s AS DATE), MONTH)
FROM (
  SELECT '2017-02-17' AS s UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-02-14' AS s
);
```

Comment: Nice answer Elliott. TIL that it's possible to cast a string to a date! `CAST(s AS DATE)`

Answer (score 0):

If the input is in strings, you can do string manipulations instead of dropping into DATE type, here are couple of possibilities:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  REGEXP_REPLACE(s, r'({\d}4-{\d}2)-{\d}2', '\\1-01'),
  CONCAT(SUBSTR(s, 0, 7), '-01')
FROM (
  SELECT '2017-02-17' AS s UNION ALL
  SELECT '2017-02-14' AS s UNION ALL
  SELECT '1985-08-31' AS s
);
```